# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS auto shut down problem

Tags: 20.04, power-management, shutdown, automatic

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my hp notebook. It shuts down automatically even when battery is not low. My pc does not have graphics card.

I have tried disabling auto power off using `dconfig` but it doesn't work. This was not happening when I was using Windows 10. This problem does not occur while plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Ubuntu is trying to enter low-power mode.
This is evident by the part where you said the laptop has no GPU.
Low power mode turns off the GPU, but in this case it's integrated graphics so it's accidentally killing the computer.
The solution should be to go into settings and make it sleep instead of entering low power mode, or disable that entirely.

If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: thanks it worked!

Comment: How did you disable the low-power mode?
I seem to have the same problem but cannot find anything in the normal settings of Ubuntu 20.04